# Как разбить строку с текстом в список?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст вида:

"1) первый вопрос 2) второй вопрос 3)вопрос и тд"

Как наименее трудозатратно (наименьшим кодом) его можно распарсить в массив строк по номерам. Понятно что можно посимвольно считывать, запоминать позицию, вырезать подстроку, но может есть более простое решение, м.б. регулярки?

Comment: @Kromster, да что-то в "одну строчку" более наглядно, возможно регулярные выражения

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно и регуляркой:

```
var text = "1) первый вопрос 2) второй вопрос 3)вопрос и тд";
var pattern = @"\s*\d+\)\s*";
var result = Regex.Split(text, pattern)
                  .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)) // Выбросим пустые куски (первый точно будет пустым)
                  .ToList();
```

Здесь:

```
\s* — Любое количество пробельных символов
\d+ — Одна или более цифр
\)  — Закрывающая скобка
\s* — Любое количество пробельных символов
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Если вы хотите запомнить также и номер вопроса, то можно сделать это в 2 этапа: сначала разбиваем строку на куски по `\d+\)` не включая само совпадение, а потом из каждого куска выбрать отдельно номер и тело вопроса:

```
var text = "1) первый вопрос 2) второй вопрос 3)вопрос и тд";
var splitPattern = @"(?<!^)(?=\d+\))";
var result = Regex.Split(text, splitPattern);
var selectPattern = @"(\d+)\s*\)\s*(.+)";
var questions = result.Select(r => Regex.Match(r, selectPattern).Groups)
                      .ToDictionary(g => g[1].Value, g => g[2].Value);
```

Здесь:

```
В выражении для разбиения:
(?<!...) — Негативный просмотр назад, т.е. находим (не)совпадение перед тем местом, по которому нужно разрезать строку, но само совпадение не включаем в результат
^        — Начало строки
(?=...)  — Позитивный просмотр вперед, т.е. находим совпадение после того места, по которому нужно разрезать строку, но само совпадение не включаем в результат
\d+      — Одна или более цифр
\)       — Закрывающая скобка

В выражении для выбора номера и тела вопроса:
(\d+)    — Одна или более цифр, помещаем в первую группу (потом будем использовать в качестве ключа словаря: g[1]
\s*      — Любое количество пробельных символов (вне групп, т.к. они нам не нужны)
\)       — Закрывающая скобка (вне групп)
\s*      — Любое количество пробельных символов (вне групп)
(.+)     — Все символы до конца строки, помещаем во вторую группу
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо в один этап:

```
var text = "1) первый вопрос 2) второй вопрос 3)вопрос и тд";
var pattern = @"(\d+)\s*\)\s*(.+?)(?=\s*(\d+\)|$))";
var questions = Regex.Matches(text, pattern)
                     .OfType<Match>()
                     .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups[1].Value, m => m.Groups[2].Value);
```

Здесь:

```
(\d+)     — Одна или более цифр, помещаем в первую группу
\s*       — Любое количество пробельных символов, вне групп
\)        — Закрывающая скобка, вне групп
\s*       — Любое количество пробельных символов, вне групп
(.+?)     — Любые символы, здесь ленивый выбор, иначе будет захвачена вся строка за один раз
(?=...)   — Позитивный просмотр вперед
\s*       — Любое количество пробельных символов
(...|...) — Или то или то
\d+\)     — Одна или более цифр + зарывающая скобка
$         — Конец строки
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интересный способ, а нумерацию в массиве можно сохранить?

Comment: А она у вас может идти не по порядку?

Comment: `[^^]    — Любые символы, кроме начала строки` - неверно, `[^^]` находит любой знак кроме знака `^`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, согласен, просто на данном конкретном примере сработало, а я не удосужился проверить на других. Спасибо за замечание — исправил!